# Logcat Error occurred at the end of registration

Tags: android, authentication, registration

I can’t able to register into my application.So that I couldn’t able to log in to my application.Below I am posted the codes related to that.

**Login.java:**

```
package com.steph.register;

public class Login extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set up the login form.
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        mEmailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        // Action listener to focus on the login process based on the key input.
        mPasswordView
                .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id,
                            KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                            attemptLogin();
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });


    //Method to clear the registration details.
    private void clearRegistrationCredinals() {
        mRegisterEmailView.setText(null);
        mRegisterPasswordView.setText(null);
        mRegisterRePasswordView.setText(null);
    }
    }

}
```

Then I am getting a log cat message like this:

**Logcat:**

```
10-06 10:18:22.722: D/SAM(1321): UserRegisterTask -> doInBackground
10-06 10:18:22.722: D/SAM(1321): http://********************************
10-06 10:18:22.732: D/keys->password_confirmation(1321):  | value->*********
10-06 10:18:22.732: D/keys->password(1321):  | value->*********
10-06 10:18:22.732: D/keys->email(1321):  | value->ssteph9220@gmail.com
10-06 10:18:23.152: D/keys->username(1321):  | value->ssteph9220@gmail.com
10-06 10:18:23.152: D/SAM->Json(1321): {"password_confirmation":"*********","password":"*********","email":"ssteph9220@gmail.com","username":"ssteph9220@gmail.com"}
10-06 10:18:23.482: D/dalvikvm(1321): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 245K, 8% free 3936K/4256K, paused 33ms, total 34ms
10-06 10:19:27.462: E/SAM(1321): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /23.29.121.253:80 timed out
10-06 10:19:27.552: E/SAM(1321): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-06 10:19:27.602: E/SAM(1321): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 10:19:27.672: D/SAM(1321): Server Reply -> Error
```

- But Logcat error doesn't point to any of the Line.I didn't know how
  to solve this.Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: PLease correct me if I am wrong:

You have 2 or more tabs. 1) Home 2) Youtube Fragment
And You are using ViewPager?

Comment: what does your logger show. Is the problem `HttpManager` or even before that.

Comment: @ashoke there was no problem in that.

Comment: add log messages inside `attemptRegister` and see if you are getting values before the call to `HttpManager`

Comment: @ashoke yes,before going to `HttpManager`,I gotta call in Logcat.

Comment: logcat shows network issues, are you able to access that url using device/emulator you are using to test

Comment: Have you tried testing the endpoint with POSTMAN to ensure that the server is giving back valid responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see presently the api is not working...

```
//Perform user registration task using AsyncTask in the background.
public class UserRegisterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Logger.debug("UserRegisterTask", "doInBackground");
        try {
    //      String url = Settings.baseUrl + "users";
            JSONObject oJSONObject = new JSONObject();
            oJSONObject.put("email", mEmail);
            oJSONObject.put("username", mEmail);
            oJSONObject.put("password", mPassword);
            oJSONObject.put("password_confirmation", mPassword);
            //Make a Post method to create the new user.
    //      Users usr = JsonManager.parseUser(HttpManager.post(url,
    //              oJSONObject));
            /*if (usr.getUserID() != 0) {
                UserManager.setUserDetails(getApplicationContext(), usr);
                return "Success";
            }*/

        } catch (Throwable th) {
            Logger.error(th);
        }
        return "Success";
    }
```

you are not initialize the usr variable but you are trying to get the data from it. So i comment that code. now it works.

Comment: Ok.Thank you for all your help :) Registration success.